# Dropdown is not listing countries imported from https://disease.sh/ in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am trying to learn react js and followinf some tutorial. i tried to import countries list to my dropdown but the dropdown looks blank and i have no idea how to fix this one.

here is my app.js

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'; 
import './App.css';
import { MenuItem,Select,FormControl } from '@material-ui/core';




function App() {
  const [countries, setCountries] = useState([]);



  useEffect(() => {
     const getCountriesData =  async () => {
       await fetch("https://disease.sh/v3/covid19-/countries")
       .then((response) => response.json())
       .then((data)  => {
         const countries = data.map((country) => (
           {
             name: country.country,
             value: country.countryInfo.iso2
           }
         ));
         setCountries(countries);
       });
     };

     getCountriesData();
  }, []);
 
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="app__header">
        <h1> COVID 19 TRACKER </h1>
        <FormControl className="app__dropdown">
          <Select variant="outlined"  value="abc">
             {countries.map(country => (
                
               <MenuItem value={country.value}> { country.name } </MenuItem>
             ))}
          </Select>
      </FormControl>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

the file compiled without any error but i still dont get any result. also it would be helpfull how should i debug in this kind of case, thanks and sorry for my poor english.

Comment: I think you are hitting wrong endpoint of the API, correct one is https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/countries, there is a typo error in your url.

Comment: Thank @AmitMondal you saved my night thank you so much

Comment: Also, you don't need to call the method inside useEffect() as it's already behaving like a 'componentdidmount'. Also don't mix async/await with promise().then().catch(), use any one of them. Happy learning!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your await syntax is wrong.[Refer this](http://%20https://dev.to/shoupn/javascript-fetch-api-and-using-asyncawait-47mp)

```
 useEffect(() => {
        const getCountriesData = async () => {
            const response = await fetch("https://disease.sh/v3/covid19-/countries")
            const data = await response.json();
            return data;
    
        };
    
        getCountriesData().then((data) => {
            const countries = data.map((country) => (
                {
                    name: country.country,
                    value: country.countryInfo.iso2
                }
            ));
            setCountries(countries);
        });
     }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a second parameter for useEffect and it is empty, you could try removing it.

Comment: That is for calling the API after render, similar to componentDidMount